# Disable logging in neo4j Java client application using bolt driver

Tags: java, neo4j

I'm connecting with Java to neo4j using the GraphDatabase.driver and I have this log4j.properties file which suppresses the output of HBase and MongoDB but doesn't work with neo4j:

```
log4j.rootLogger=OFF, stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c{2}: %m%n
```

The logging output that shows up in the client application looks like this:

```
Mär 15, 2018 11:20:03 AM org.neo4j.driver.internal.logging.JULogger info
INFORMATION: Closing driver instance org.neo4j.driver.internal.InternalDriver@6743e411
Mär 15, 2018 11:20:03 AM org.neo4j.driver.internal.logging.JULogger info
INFORMATION: Closing connection pool towards localhost:7687
Mär 15, 2018 11:20:05 AM org.neo4j.driver.internal.logging.JULogger info
```

How can this be disabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JULogger of the neo4j GraphDatabase.driver can be disabled using the java.util.logging.LogManager

```
LogManager.getLogManager().reset();
```

This will disable the logging, thus even suppress error messages. If just the INFO message shown in the example output should be suppressed then the log level has to be changed.

```
Logger rootLogger = LogManager.getLogManager().getLogger("");
rootLogger.setLevel(Level.SEVERE);
for (Handler h : rootLogger.getHandlers())
    h.setLevel(Level.SEVERE);
```

Comment: This code is BAD, because it disables logging not only for Neo4j, but for the whole application. For example, on application server if you put it in Neo4j bean, it will disable all appserver logging anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
<logger name="org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.http" level="WARN" additivity="false"></logger>
```

Comment: Please add some comments describing how this code answers the question.

Comment: This is the package name of the spring blot driver used by spring. By using spring's logback. xml, you can prohibit printing by adding this to it.